# How to create List View for Service Contract with only My Records?

Tags: sobject, list-view, filters

I want to create a custom list view for showing only my created records. As in `Account` or any other `sobject` there is an option of "Filter By Owner:" under "Step 2. Specify Filter Criteria" section but for `ServiceContract`, I am not able to find it.

Comment: Please do not use ALL CAPS. It is the internet equivalent of screaming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Service Contract object list view doesn’t have the `Filter by Owner` option for now.However, as a workaround, you can create a custom formula field in that object with checkbox as the return type and use the below formula:

```
IF( OwnerId = $User.Id, TRUE,FALSE)
```

The checkbox will return `TRUE` if the running `user ID` is equals to Record `Owner ID`, otherwise it will return `FALSE`.Then you can use that formula field as a filter to list view.

Also you can Upvote this [Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003Tr0QAE)